# Which is the best feasible solution for sharing the data from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ios

here is my scenario, i am building a web application using PHP and MySQL. basically it is a real estate application. where i would like to share the data among several other platforms and devices, here is i what i intend to do

a) building the web app to be used with the browser using PHP, MySQL, and AJAX. (this will be my server)

b) extend the support and build a desktop application using [POKKI](http://www.pokki.com/).

c) extend the support and build an application for Androids and iOS devices.

d) all data transaction for the app should take place from the web server.

e) basically it will be server client application . where the server will be my web server and the clients will be iOS app, Android App  Pokki etc.

i am not a hardcore programmer, although it has been more then 1 year since i started using PHP, and i do understand it to my use. i would like to know the best feasible solution on how to share the data among the different clients(POKKI, iOS App, Android App).

i would like to know.

a) do i have to connect to database directly from the client and access the data? is it possible? is it bad if i go this way?

b) do i have to create a public class with api sign up process? what would be the real scenario if i would like it to make it cross platform.

A Humble request to all of you to guide me on how does this things works. any articles, resources, links that can prove useful to me will also be appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create an API which allows you to access the database strictly as you want it. Look at the twitter API for example and see how it allows third parties to access their data using simple requests.

So your site uses the DB directly where as all other applications you want to make will use the API ( which runs on ur web server)

This would allow you with the flexibility to have control who gets access and who doesnt ( only your own apps or even third parties etc etc) and allows you to build kick-ass applications without putting your actual database at risk.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes i do intend to create a twiiter like api so that i decide on who can access the data. do i have to take the help of XML along with it? i have no idea how does this api things work?

Answer (score 2):

1 - you should not allow client to access data directly - bad.
2 - sign up are easy with open id, let google or any other openid provider handle authentication, you deal with your own clean code without worrying about auth. 
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

Comment: thank you for that valuable point i appreciate it . but i think you have got it wrong. what i would like to know is how can i make my app to be used for cross platform? i.e how do i share the data from the database to different clients or platform(not users).

Comment: clients means Windows/Linux/Mac in your context ? pls clarify ?

Comment: if yes, you could use simple delimited files or csv and convert them back in local db.. CSV are common formats used by almost all db providers

Comment: nope client in the sense different languages like COCOA, Objective-C, Java, Javascript, AJAX etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create xml api and share the data from your server.
On different type of client you can eaisly parse the xml data and process it or show it.

In xml API if you want the restrict access then your can provide the restriction.

Please let me know if you have any issue

Thanks and Regards,
Ankur K Singh

Comment: thank you for the tip. i haven't used XML Before, although i have the idea what exactly it is. i am not so sure how will i be using it for my application. time for me to start digging. thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

take a look into [getfrapi.com](http://getfrapi.com) for building API.